# How to copy data in Python

Tags: python, list, copy, compare

After entering a command I am given data, that I then transform into a list. Once transformed into a list, how do I copy ALL of the data from that list [A], and save it - so when I enter a command and am given a second list of data [B], I can compare the two; and have data that is the same from the two lists cancel out - so what is not similar between [A] & [B] is output. For example...

```
List [A]
1
2
3

List [B]
1
2
3
4
```

Using Python, I now want to compare the two lists to each other, and then output the differences.

```
Output = 4
```

Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: So you want to enter the two lists and show the differences between the two files?

Comment: @karthikr thanks for cleaning that up

Comment: Where's the connection to copying as the title states?

Comment: Is entering the data also an issue?

Comment: No, entering the data is not an issue. I just needed a way to compare the two data lists, and then output the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> b=[1,2,3,4]
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> [x for x in b if x not in a]
[4]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use set operations.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3,4]

print set(b) - set(a)
```

to output the data in list format you can use the following print statement

```
print list(set(b) - set(a))
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite right.  He never said there were no duplicates.  For example [1,1,2] - [1,2] would be the empty set instead of a list containing [1].

Comment: *she, and ^True, but I do not think I will encounter that problem with the data I have. How do I output that set with just the differences? Without it saying>> set(['sd4', 'sd99'])

Answer (score 0):

```
for element in b:
    if element in a:
        a.remove(element)
```

This answer will return a list not a set, and should take duplicates into account.  That way [1,2,1] - [1,2] returns [1] not [].

Answer (score 0):

Try `itertools.izip_longest`

```
import itertools

a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3,4]

[y for x, y in itertools.izip_longest(a, b) if x != y]
# [4]
```

You could easily modify this further to return a duple for each difference, where the first item in the duple is the position in `b` and the second item is the value.

```
[(i, pair[1]) for i, pair in enumerate(itertools.izip_longest(a, b)) if pair[0] != pair[1]]
# [(3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

For entering the data use a loop:

```
def enterList():
  result = []
  while True:
    value = raw_input()
    if value:
      result.append(value)
    else:
      return result

A = enterList()
B = enterList()
```

For comparing you can use `zip` to build pairs and compare each of them:

```
for a, b in zip(A, B):
  if a != b:
    print a, "!=", b
```

This will truncate the comparison at the length of the shorter list; use the solution in another answer given here using `itertools.izip_longest()` to handle that.